# How to convert a date of any language to a specific language

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter, nslocale

How to convert a date of any language(Arabic) to a specific language(English).

While changing the region format to arabic, the dates are getting changed. When I am picking the date value from some controls(UIButtons or UILabels) for saving in database, its picking the date in arabic language and saving in the same format. Here I want to convert the date from arabic to english before saving it in database.

I tried this but its returning nil

```
NSDate *currentDate = //My date coming like  “٢٠١٤-٠٥-١٥ ١٢:١٠:٢٣ ”
NSDateFormatter *formatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSLocale *usLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
[formatter setLocale: usLocale];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:s a"];
NSString *formattedDate = [formatter stringFromDate: currentDate];
```

Can anyone please help me ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I solved in this way

```
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:timeZone];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:s"];
    NSLocale *usLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
    [dateFormatter setLocale:usLocale];
    NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:myDate];
```

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't store dates in *any* language. You should store NSDate, which has no language or locale or time zone, and display it as appropriate. If your database cannot store NSDate, you can store [myDate timeIntervalSince1970] and convert it to an NSDate using the class method dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:

Comment: Thanks for your reply Gnasher729

Answer (score 0):

You should use UIDatePicker as the input instead of UIButtons or UILabels. Save the timeIntervalSince1970 into your database, so that it can be presented by any language.

```c
NSDate *currentDate = //My date coming like  “٢٠١٤-٠٥-١٥ ١٢:١٠:٢٣ ”
NSTimeInterval timeToBeSavedInDatabase = [currentDate timeIntervalSince1970];
//in the future, you can show this date in any language
NSString *dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970]];
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use this to get the date with preferred local

```
 NSDate * dateNow = [NSDate new];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

NSLocale *usLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];

[dateFormat setLocale: usLocale];

[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];

NSString *   dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:dateNow];
```